# Error in code when tryin to create table for my ads

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE  `animals`.`ads_DB` (

`id` DOUBLE( 25 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`subcategory` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`mobile_no` DOUBLE( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`phone_no` DOUBLE( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`city` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`state` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`country` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`photo` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

MySQL said:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `category` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `subcat' at line 1

Comment: Do you really need your `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID field to be a `DOUBLE( 25 )`?

Comment: You can use the DOUBLE type if you want to, but they are not useful for ID's or phone numbers. Double is a floating point type, so when storing an integer you should use one of the [integer types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), if you're worried about a big id number you can use a unsigned BIGINT, ranging from 0 to 18446744073709551615 :-) should keep your ads going for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified precision correctly for all your `DOUBLE` fields. The query should be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE  `animals`.`ads_DB` (

`id` DOUBLE( 25, 15 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`subcategory` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`mobile_no` DOUBLE( 25, 15 ) NOT NULL ,
`phone_no` DOUBLE( 25, 15 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`city` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`state` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`country` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`photo` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Notice how I've changed the `DOUBLE(...)` - you have to specify how many total digits you want and how many after the decimal point. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) for more information.

Why are you using doubles anyway? Seems very odd for the values that you need to store.

Comment: int is small for mobile no, so should i use BIGINT?

Comment: Well, it makes no sense to use a double. It depends on what numbers (and possibly symbols) you want to store, i.e. you might want to have a + sign in there, leading zeros (which could be done by using ZEROFILL, but there are some limitations too), etc. But if it's just a number use and integer. Also, double as an auto incrementing primary key is... weird :)

Comment: i m using bigint now , could you let me know the length that should be given for that , although it is working fine without giving any length and i made it unsigned BIGINT

Comment: Maximum size of what - your numbers or the bigint? An unsigned bigint stores up to 20 digits, but the maximum value is 18446744073709551615, meaning that if you use all 20 digits the first cannot be greater than 1. If you need more than 20 digits (are there phones that long?!), you could use varchar, after all you're not gonna be doing any arithmetics on the phone number and the memory impact is not that big...